# Redirect IP to a domain name using htaccess

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, .htaccess

Let's say I have this IP Address `11.12.13.14` and the domain `example.com`. Now what I want is to redirect the user from IP Address to domain name (but without changing the domain name to address bar). So when the user requests `11.12.13.14/test` it should open `exapmle.com/test` but not to redirect to domain name, in the address bar it should still remain `11.12.13.14/test`.

I have seen this question [Redirect to other domain but keep typed domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009901). I don't know if it works because I haven't tested it, but I suppose it does.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with Apache, so is there any wat to achieve this?

Here is what I have tried

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ 11.12.13.14$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,P]
```

Comment: Maybe you should test it and THEN post a new question if it doesn't work. Showing some effort will tend to lead to better answers or feedback here.

Comment: Yes but it is to redirect Domain A to Domain B. I need to redirect IP to Domain. I tried it, but I think I have made any mistake when I changed from Domain A to IP.

Comment: If you've tried something, you should include your attempted configurations in the question so that people can build on or provide advice to what you've done.

Comment: See the edit :)

Comment: Is that ip-address the actual ip-address of example.com or is example.com pointing to a different web server entirely?

Comment: It's a different one, there is no connection between IP Address and the domain name.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really **redirect** without changing an address displayed in bar. If you want a similar effect, you have at least two options:

1. reverse proxy (*mod_proxy_http*) - possibly transparent to user;
2. HTML frame - obsolete, easy to detect and prone to fail with modern browsers.

**Edit #1:**
For proxy solution, you need to place the directives below in global or VirtualHost (IP-based) section:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
    ProxyPass "/" "http://example.com/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://example.com/"
<IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you  show an example code for the first option, I can't really use HTML frame in my case.

Comment: Edited, included samples.